# Axiom of Union for set that consists of 1 element

Tags: logic, set-theory, axioms

I'm having some difficulty understanding the axiom of union. As the axiom of union says:

> For any set $x$ there is a set $y$ whose elements are precisely the elements of the elements of $x$.

So for example, for two sets $A = \{1,2\}, B = \{3,4\}$ I know by the axiom of pairs that a set $C=\{\{1,2\}, \{3,4\}\} $ exists, and by the axiom of unions that $\{1,2,3,4\}$ is also a set. But my problem comes when I apply the axiom of unions to a single element set (I can't find any examples online).
For example:

Let define $0$ as $\emptyset$ and $1$ as $\{\emptyset\}$

Is  $\bigcup \{1\}$ = $\{1\}$ or $\bigcup \{ 1\} = \{ \emptyset\} = 1$?

Comment: $$\bigcup\{A,B,C\}=A\cup B\cup C,$$ right? So if $A=B=C,$ then $$\bigcup\{A,A,A\}=A\cup A\cup A,$$ that is, $$\bigcup\{A\}=A.$$

Comment: I think converting it to English as you did to the axiom of union helps. So it will be the elements of the elements of $ \{1\}$ or in other words the elements of 1. So it is $\{\emptyset\}= 1$

Comment: Thanks a lot! That helped me to ensure my suspicions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The axiom of union takes a layer of $\{\}$ off of elements. You have $1=\{\{\}\}=\{\emptyset\}$ and so applying the axiom of union to $\{1\}$ produces $1=\{\emptyset\}$. In general, applying it to $\{a\}$ produces $a$.